# How to pre-process third party JS script with Webpack to run it in the same project context?

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron, vue-cli

I use [vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/) plugin (based on [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/)) to deliver Win desktop Electron app.

The app project has third party dependency. Let's call it "ABC":

```
package.json
"dependencies": {
    "ABC": "^x.x.x",
}
```

"ABC" exports the only one function `init()` so in *main.js* I can import and run the function

```js
import * as init from 'ABC'
init()
```

There is a call inside of the function `init()`:

```js
var fork = require('child_process').fork;
script = 'someOutsideScript.js'
fork(script, []);
```

*someOutsideScript.js* contains `require('anyModule')` and has no export entities

**Problem:**
When *someOutsideScript.js* is executed the error `Cannot find module 'anyModule' is thrown`.
If I copy `anyModule` in node_modules the application works properly.

The plugin uses Webpack to process source code.
Webpack builds a dependency graph based on source code "import-s/require-s". *someOutsideScript.js* isn't supposed to be processed because there are no references to this script in source code. It is just executed by 'fork'. `require('anyModule')` works without troubles in *main.js*

**Question:**
How to share the same module loading context in *main.js* and *someOutsideScript.js*? Is there any way to pre-process *someOutsideScript.js* static script to avoid `Cannot find module exception`?

Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5445